# Delete lines which have a particular word

Tags: regex, text-editors

I have a list of links like this

```
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/dogs-24x100.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/dogs-640x2648.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/dogs-72x300.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/dogs-large.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/dogs-medium.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/dogs-small.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/dogs.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cats-24x100.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cats-640x2648.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cats-72x300.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cats-large.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cats-medium.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cats-small.png
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cats.png
```

How do I delete the lines which have -large , -medium , -small , and end with -numberxnumber ? Platform - Windows 7 . Notepad++ and Sublime Text 2 installed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be doing it regularly, get hold of `grep.exe`, ported from Unix, then create a batch file containing:

```
grep <"%1" -v -E -e "-large|-medium|-small|-24x100|-72x300|-640x2048" >"%1.pruned
```

Make sure that the `grep` port supports `-E`. If not you will need a succession of calls:

```
grep <"%1" -v -e "-large" | grep -v -e "-medium" | grep ...
```

The `-e` option is needed because all the search strings start with `-`.

Comment: Is this the one ? http://www.wingrep.com/

Comment: I was thinking of a command-line port, such as in UnxUpdates.zip from the [GNU Utilities](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/). You may be able to use a GUI version, but not in a batch file.

Comment: How to use it ? I have over 50 files I need to edit . Your command has no "filename" in it .I downloaded UnxUpdates.zip . grep.exe closes when I open it . Do I have to add it in environmental variables ?

Comment: You need to run it from `cmd`, when it displays `Usage: grep OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...` / `Try 'grep --help' for more information.` My command should be saved to a batch file, such as `prune.cmd`: `%1` refers to a file name you pass as a parameter, as in `prune "File 1"`. The file with the deleted entries will be `"File 1.pruned"`. Once you are confident that it is working as you expect you can replace the original file by adding `del "%1"` and `ren "%1.pruned" "%1"` to the batch file

Comment: Finally, if you have a unique name pattern or extension for the files you need to process, you can process all the files in a single command, such as: `for %f in (Pattern*.extn) do call prune "%f"`

Comment: Thanks .Looks like it worked . 7mb txt file became 5mb file . There are still many links with -3digitnumberx3digitnumber ,-onedigitx2digit,-fourdigitx3digit,-3digitx4digit .Any expression for that ? -numberxnumber ?

Comment: The expression `-e "-[0-9]+x[0-9]+"` matches `-{one or more digits}x{one or more digits}`, so the grep expression becomes `-e "-large|-medium|-small|-[0-9]+x[0-9]+"`.

Comment: If you update your question, I'll put the new expression in my answer.

Comment: I edited the last line of the question . There is one more thing . I found that there are links like dogs.jpg ,dogs1.jpg,dogs2.jpg . Same for cats . For that expression will be "[0-9]+.jpg" right ? Also as I said I have over 50 files . Can I specify all filenames seperated by a comma or will I have to run the command for each file seperately ?

Comment: The capital `-E` allows all the match terms to be concatenated within a single expression, eg: `-E "a|b"` matches lines containing `a` or `b` and `-v` means list files which do _not_ match, so you can just add `|regexp1|regexp2 ...` for any additional names you wish to exclude. Your expression is nearly correct and would probably work, but it ought to be `[0-9]+\.jpg` so as to match `{digit}.jpg` instead of `{digit}{any character}jpg`.

Comment: I wrote it wrong . I meant I want to delete the files . They are duplicates . Is my expression right ?  "[0-9]+.jpg" ?

Answer (score 0):

I've always had excel open on my desktop so use that alot.

Open the list in excel, filter on the column, then filter out the words that contain what you don't want. copy and paste the list to a new sheet and save

Comment: The tags are "regex" and "text-editor"